# How can I write a formula to delete a value in a cell in excel when any date is added to the corresponding cell

Tags: excel

[image]

I would like to add a formula which can help me to dele the data in a cell in Column M if I add any date in a cell in column J.

Comment: A formula cannot change the value of any cell but the one in which it is placed.  You will want vba in a worksheet change event.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. would it be possible for you to help with any VBA code for the same? It would be of great help as I am struggling a bit here.

Comment: That is not what this site is for.  We help overcome specific problems with existing code, not write from scratch.

Comment: Aah okay, Sorry I am new here so did not know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

' Date in Column "J"
Private Const DateColumn As Long = 10
' Destination in Column "M"
Private Const DestinationColumn = 13

' Data Area
Private Const DataRowBegin As Long = 10
Private Const DataRowEnd As Long = 20

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Variant
Dim V As Variant
   
   For Each C In Target
      If (C.Row >= DataRowBegin) And (C.Row <= DataRowEnd) Then
         If C.Column = DateColumn Then
            V = ActiveSheet.Cells(C.Row, C.Column)
            If (V <> "") Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(C.Row, DestinationColumn) = ""
            End If
         End If
      End If
   Next
End Sub
```

You must insert the code in VBA (for example "Sheet1").